# Disable WordPress plugin per request

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to get Wordpress to disable a plugin for a single page visit using URL args?

For e.g. `example.com/?disable_plugin=akismet/akismet.php`

So far I've tried the following:

```
deactivate_plugins( 
    $disable_pluggins_arr,
    true, // silent mode (no deactivation hooks fired)
    false // network wide
);
```

This works hover it's also disabled globally. Same goes for using `options_active_plugins` hook

```
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', function( $plugins ){
    $plugins = array_diff( $plugins, $disable_pluggins_arr );
    return $plugins;
});
```

It disables the plugins but it's stored in the database and visiting any other page will not have them active.

How can I temporarily bypass a plugin from loading when using `?disable_plugin=akismet/akismet.php` for that request;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible but the corresponding code **cannot** be written in the `functions.php` or in an ordinary plugin. You **MUST** create your own `mu-plugin` for this. Read more about Must-Use-Plugins [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/plugins/mu-plugins/).

Your filter hook is ok but you need to define where to fire and where not to fire. Also the wp-admin path should be excluded (the backend).

So create a new subfolder `mu-plugins` under `wp-content`. Next, take the snippet below and create a file with it (e.g. `bypass-plugins.php`). Copy the file to `/wp-content/mu-plugins/`. Finally, adjust the variables `$bypass_path` and `$bypass_plugins` to your needs.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Bypass Plugins
 * Description: Bypass WordPress plugins on a specific page.
 * Version:     1.0.0
 */

# no direct access
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    header( 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden' );
    exit;
}

# the bypass path
$bypass_path = '/some-path/';

# plugins to be bypassed
$bypass_plugins = [
    'akismet/akismet.php',
    'hello.php'
];

# get url path from request
$url_path = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH );

# check if in the backend
$is_backend = strpos( $url_path, '/wp-admin/' );

# check for bypass path
$is_bypass_path = strpos( $url_path, $bypass_path );

# not in the backend but bypass path detected - do the magic
if ( $is_backend === false && $is_bypass_path !== false ) {

    /* To make things work we need the option_{$option} hook and use it on a filter.
     * https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/option_option/
     *
     * The 'option_active_plugins' filter hook returns an array of active plugins.
     * With the help of PHP array_diff we remove the plugins to be bypassed from
     * the array of active plugins and return it.
     */
    add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', function ( $plugins ) use ( $bypass_plugins ) {
        return array_diff( $plugins, $bypass_plugins );
    } );
}
```